# Hide multiple posts on home page on Blogger

Tags: blogger

I am trying to hide all posts the ones with the label "Master Gardener"

I have used this code and it works but I cannot see the post with the label "Master Gardener". This post only has one label. Here is the site http://upcommunitygarden.blogspot.com/

```html
<b:if cond='data:blog.url == data:blog.homepageUrl'>
    <b:loop values='data:post.labels' var='label'>
        <b:if cond='data:label.isLast == "true"'>
            <b:if cond='data:label.name != "Education""Projects"'>
                <b:include data='post' name='post' />
            </b:if>
        </b:if>
    </b:loop>
<b:else/>
    <b:include data='post' name='post' />
</b:if>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `data:post.labels.length == "1"` to check if post has one label

```
<b:if cond='data:blog.url == data:blog.homepageUrl and data:post.labels.length == "1"'>
    <b:loop values='data:post.labels' var='label'>
        <b:if cond='data:label.name != "Master Gardener"'>
            <b:include data='post' name='post' />
        </b:if>
    </b:loop>
<b:else/>
    <b:include data='post' name='post' />
</b:if>
```

Comment: When I use this code all posts show up. Not just the ones with the label "Master Gardener". The post only has one label.

Comment: This code will hide all posts with label "Master Gardener" if post only has one label on home page and not other index pages. to hide your label on index pages use `data:blog.pageType == "index"` instead of `data:blog.url == data:blog.homepageUrl` (index pages include label pages, search pages and pages when you click Older Posts)

Answer (score 0):

your codes are bad.

Replace:

```
<b:loop values='data:posts' var='post'>
```

by :

```
<b:loop values='data:view.isMultipleItems ? data:posts where (p => p.labels none (l => l.name in {"Education","Projects"})) : data:posts' var='post'>
```

Comment: Please avoid just post the code as answer. Add more information like what is wrong.

Comment: To filter, use a ternary operator in the loop and redefine a new array: Condition ? array if true : array if false.  If true, use a lambda operator to filter the array: data:posts where (p => p.labels none (l => l.name in {"Education","Projects"})). If false, display full array: data:posts.